# Create menu tabs with views

Tags: views, 8, navigation

**How can create menu views tabs of node?** In Drupal 7 i can create views like this:

> [image: Setting views]
>
> [image: Setting menu]

when i visit node/1/teaser it's show good.

> [image: Node view]

But with same setting in drupal 8.

> [image: Drupal 8 Setting]

when i visit node/1 show error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException:
>   Some mandatory parameters are missing ("arg_0") to generate a URL for
>   route "view.menu_tabs.page_1". in
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 171 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

and node/1/teaser show error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException:
>   Some mandatory parameters are missing ("node") to generate a URL for
>   route "entity.node.devel_load". in
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 171 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2511892) in views.

The issue is that the route parameter for entities needs to be named:

> This view will be displayed by visiting this path on your site. You
>   may use "%" or named route parameters like "%node" in your URL to
>   represent values that will be used for contextual filters: For
>   example, "node/%node/feed" or "view_path/%". The named route
>   parameters are necessary when used within paths used by entities such
>   as "taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term" or "user/%user/custom-view

This is for the first error message.

The second one is caused by the devel module. If you still get this error after renaming the route parameter, you have to check the issue queue from this module.